# Please report: Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501. Some pending callbacks that might have leaked by never being called from native code

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm getting the contact list from the user phone by using `import * as Contacts from 'expo-contacts';` library.

When I go to the screen that gets the list of the contacts, I get this error:

```
Please report: Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501. Some pending callbacks that might have leaked by never being called from native code
```

To do that I'm using an useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
      console.log('status', status);
      if (status === 'granted') {
        const { data } = Contacts.getContactsAsync({
          fields: [Contacts.Fields.PhoneNumbers],
        });
        if (data.length > 0) {
          setContacts(data);
        }
      }
    })();

    AsyncStorage.getItem('Credentials')
      .then((result) => {
        if (result !== null) {
          setPhone(JSON.parse(result).phone);
          setName(JSON.parse(result).fullName);
        } else {
          setPhone(null);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: What's in the useEffect dependency array? Probably you're changing something in there that causes it to re-render

Comment: the dependecy is [] in this useEffect. I noticed that if I comment setContatcs(data) the error will not be shown

Comment: are there any other useEffects that depend on `contacts`?

Comment: No, its not any other useEffect, but in other components yes.